# I need to extract data from database using ajax in django

Tags: html, mysql, django, ajax, web-development-server

I need to extract data from the database and view the results on a chart in the view, the charts should change dynamically when the values in the database change(the model is done to get the data of users after submitting a survey

Here is my model.

```
class Survey(models.Model):

    gender=models.CharField(max_length=200)  
    Age = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    Nationality=models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    Gorvernate = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Maritalstatus=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Employmentstatus=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    children=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Education =models.CharField(max_length=200)
    IncomePerMonth=models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'form_surey'
```

I tried this in the view:

```
<script>

$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "{% url 'pie-chart' %}",
            data: {{gender}},
            success: function (response) {
                // if not valid user, alert the user
                if(!response["valid"]){
                    alert("Success");
            
                }
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log(response)
            }
        });

const labels = ['Male','Female'];
const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Gender',
    backgroundColor: ['rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      'rgb(54, 162, 235)', 
      ],
    borderColor:[ 'rgb(255, 99, 132)', 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',

  ],
    data: {{gender|safe}},
  }]
};

const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: {}
};


  // === include 'setup' then 'config' above ===

  var myChart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('myChart'),
    config
  );



</script>
```

Comment: Hi there, you need a frontend framework like VueJS or React that can listen for changes and update them dynamically.

Comment: You can use Vue in just one page, so that you don't need to configure all the frontend application, use Vue to make your page reactivy and use axios to make an API request.